# Why is there no determiner before 'defender' in 'the role of defender'?

Tags: articles, determiners

Just worked with [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-the-role) and found this phrase:

> He often chose to take the role of defender in the expectation of
> launching a successful counterattack.

Why is there no article before 'defender'? It is a singular countable noun, not determined by other determiners. I simply can't get my head around it.

Comment: "Defender" is here called a 'bare role' noun phrase, one that lacks a determiner. Such NPs denote some kind of role, office, or position. Compare "Ed was elected treasurer" / Kim became president".

Comment: The taste of apple in the wine (generic taste). The taste of the apple in the wine (specific apple).

Comment: @Lambie: That's interesting. Is it a property of _taste_? _The smell of apple_ works as well, and _the texture of apple_, but I'm not sure about  _the look of apple_ or _the sound of apple_. I'm also not sure about _the taste of pea_, or _the taste of cashew nut_, which suggest to me that this might be more about the possible use of some foods as uncountable.

Comment: @ColinFine Of course, look and sound don't work. My point was only about apple and the apple. The sound of music [in the town] was very loud. versus: The sound of the music coming from the hall was very loud. Again, generic versus specific. Of course, I am sure you can find exceptions, but still....

Comment: @Lambie: but the question was about why a determiner is not required, not about specific vs non-specific. _Music_ is uncountable, so no determiner is required. _Defender_ and (usually) _apple_ are countable, so the possibility of no determiner requires explanation.

Comment: "Apple" is a non-count noun in "The taste of apple in the wine. It is irrelevant here since it is the count status of "defender" in the original example that is puzzling the OP. –

Comment: @ColinFine I gave examples. Specific requires "the", non-specific does not; **The role of the defender in that football game**. [specific]// **The role of defender in a football game**. [generic]. "the role of defender" in the OP's question is non-specific. And these examples are exactly like my apple example.

Comment: @Lambie, as BillJ points out, in this case, _apple_ is non-count, so it is not the same.

Comment: It has nothing to do with generic. The interpretation of bare role NPs is invariably **definite**. In the original example we are concerned with the role of defender in some particular team. Such NPs are restricted to predicative complements of verbs like "be" and "become", as oblique predicatives governed by "as, and as complement of the prep "of" following nouns like "part", "position" or "role" as seen in the original example.

Comment: @ColinFIne Disagree. The difference between "the role of defender in the game' and "the role of the defenders in the game" is semantic and not grammatical. You can call it a bare noun, but the difference is semantic.  The OP did not ask what this is called; he asked about why there is no determiner. That can only be shown **constrastively**, which is exactly what I have done.

Comment: The term 'bare role' describes the kind of count singular NP that can occur without a determiner. Its name is self-explanatory: 'bare' means without a determiner and 'role' refers to the fact that such NPs describe some part, position, or role, as seen in the original example.

Answer (score 2):

> *He often chose to take the role of defender in the expectation of*
> *launching a successful counterattack.*

"Defender" is here called a 'bare role' noun phrase, one that lacks a determiner. Such NPs denote some kind of role, office, or position.

Compare *Ed was elected treasurer* / *Kim became president*.

Comment: Dear sir, the phrase in question is "the role of defender". So if your example "treasurer" is taken, and these sentences are created, 1. [Ed was offered the role of treasurer], 2. [Ed was offered the role of the treasurer], 3. [Ed was offered the role of a treasurer]: does the rule of "no articles" before "bare role noun phrase" apply?

Comment: Yes, but a determiner can be optionally added. For example, "I'd like to be treasurer" and "I'd like to be the treasurer" are both OK

Comment: But a determiner cannot be added if the NP is object: "I'd like to meet the treasurer" is OK, but **not**  "*I'd like to meet treasurer".

Comment: You do not answer: The role of defender is important in football. versus The role of defenders in football is important. Yes, the first is a bare noun but it does not explain the difference between having a determiner and not having one which can only be shown **contrastively** and semantically.

Comment: It's a matter of syntax. If it was a matter of contrast or semantics, bare role NPs could occur freely within a clause. But in fact they are restricted to predicative complements of verbs like "be" and "become", as oblique predicatives governed by "as, and as complement of the prep "of" following nouns like "part", "position" or "role" as seen in the original example.

Comment: Note also that a bare role NP can never correspond to the subject of an equivalent passive clause: we can't say *"Defender was easily beaten by the forward"; instead we need "The defender ...". And a bare role NP can never be the object of a verb. Yet more evidence that bare role NPs are to a large extent governed by syntax.

Comment: On balance, the choice of ordinary NP or bare role NP (where possible) doesn't seem to be motivated by semantics. Rather, the bare role NP seems to be the default one where there's a choice.

Comment: The role of defenders in football is important. The role of the defender was important in that game. There's nothing like avoiding real-world examples by drowning them out.

Comment: Bare role NPs are always singular, so in "The role of defenders in football is important", "defenders" does not qualify as one. It requires a determiner such as "the".

Answer (score -1):

Learning what actually works:

1. **The role of defender** in football can be very important. [a general statement]
2. **The role of the defender in that game** was crucial. [that specific defender]

This does not involve countability or not. It involves specificity and generality.

3. *The role of defenders* in football can be very important. has the same meaning as 1)

Other examples:
The role of mother is a hard one. [a general idea]
The role of mothers in our school is complicated. [general idea]

*The role of the mother* in that play is quite interesting. [specific]

Although there can always be exceptions, the structure of the examples above are very common. And, it does not matter about countability.

What matters is generality and specificity in an actual sentence.

The singular has been called a bare noun. Fine, but that does not explain the difference in meanings.

Answer (score -2):

> "Defender", "counterattack", these two words point towards multiplayer
> ball sports.

Why not "the defender"

> In these sports, there are multiple defenders. So the definite
> article was not used with "defender". The article "a" can be used with
> "defender" if one chooses to use it, though it's not mandatory.
>
> Edit: Spelling mistake corrected in the following paragraph.
>
> The phrase "the role of defender" is an NP and already has the
> definite article. This makes the use of article "a" with "defender"
> very optional.

Comment: Are the indented sections quoted from somewhere? If so, please identify where from. Neither of the paragraphs after you repeat the question makes much sense to me. As BillJ's comment on the question shows, this grammatical issue has absolutely nothing to do with "ball sports"; and nor does it depend on whether there the role is single or multiple. And "the head of a company" is an NP that already has the definite (not "definitive") article, but definitely required "a".

Comment: So you've deleted one paragraph, making the last sentence of my comment irrelevant, but left the rest.

Comment: Deleted the superfluous part and I wrote definitive (not definite) by mistake. I apologise. "The role of the head" and not "the role of a head", because there is only one "head". "The role of the head of a company"."The role of defender in a team". Sure, sometimes "The role of a head of a company" can be used if the sentence so demands.

Comment: The question was _why is there no article?_, and you have not answered that. You are addressing a different question from the one asked.

Comment: There is no point in arguing (from my side). You are more knowledgeable.